# Reading a string from data memory on 8951

Tags: assembly, embedded, 8051

I want to read a string I have defined using `db`, but it doesn't seem to work, I get some garbage instead. What is wrong?

```
MSG: DB 'This is a test string.',13,10,'Some more string.',0

CSEG at 00000h
    MOV  SP,#70H

; Hlavni smycka
main:
    MOV DPTR,#(MSG+1)

next_char:
    MOVC A,@A+DPTR  
    JZ end_of_string
    CALL fn_uart_send_byte    ; Function that sends A over UART
    INC DPTR
    JMP next_char

end_of_string:
    JMP main
```

Comment: ps when I tried to pout it in DSEG, it gave me an error. I really don't understand howto do it, there seem to be no tutorials on this

Comment: Don't you need to `CLR A` before each `MOVC`? Otherwise `A+DPTR` will use offset `DPTR` by the value you loaded during the previous iteration.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I misunderstood what `MOVC` was really doing. It works now.

Comment: (actually it doesn't QUITE work, but works better than before)

Comment: Is that because you have `MOV DPTR,#(MSG+1)` (which would skip the `"T"`) and not `MOV DPTR,#MSG`?

Comment: Yeah that was part of it, other part was that my USB-Serial cable randomly dropped bytes lol, it's all fixed and working now, thanks